# How to find at what time activity finished?

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I have activity start time and and total hour i just want to find the end time of that activity i mean time when activity finished ?

for example I start my activity 
for

```
   $hour =  24:60:08        // 24 hour 60 min 8 min total hour 
   $starttime  =  13:09     // using 24 hour format it 01:09              
                            //means activity start at =          13:09

    $endtime  = ?
```

I want to find out the the time finished time of an activity

Thanks

Comment: How are you supposed to find the end time with the given information? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: you can use datetime difference..
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

but remember to format your time correctly.. 24:00+ is not accept as i remeber

Comment: Because I have start time when user start that activity and and total running activity hour so taht we can find  for example i start an activity at 10:00 and running activity hour = 2 hour so that end time will be 12:00 oclock

Comment: So, by end time, you really mean duration, correct?

Comment: You must use   timestamp  to start event time plus add time for activity completion then  find expexted complition time

Comment: So Can we see What have you tried yet ?

Comment: no not duration ,its time like activity will be finish at 12 oclock .Activity duration we have $hour =  24:60:08  24hour 60 min 8 sec and start time 13:09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with adding to time exploded hour like following:

```
$hour      =  '24:60:08';
$starttime =  '13:09';        

$times     = explode(':', $hour);
$timestamp = strtotime($starttime) + ($times[0] * 3600 + $times[1] * 60 + $times[2]);

$endtime   = date('H:i', $timestamp);

echo $endtime; // 14:09
```

**Explain:**

```
24 = 24(hours) * 60(mins) * 60(secs)
60 = 60(mins) * 60(secs)
08 = 8(sec)
```

Comment: Just a light note, there's no such thing as 60 minutes. That `24:60:08` looks better as `25:00:08` :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears like you have a start time of an activity and then a duration of how long it ran and you want to compute what's the end time. Your question becomes unclear by your use of non descriptive variable names nor any comments. You can do

```
<?php
     $duration   =  "25:00:08";
     $starttime  =  "13:09";
     list($hours,$minutes,$seconds) = explode(":",$duration);
     $totalTime = $seconds+($minutes*60)+($hours*3600);
     $endTime = date("h:i",strtotime($starttime)+$totalTime);
     echo $endTime;
?>
```

Sidenote: `24:60:08`, **60 minutes** is nothing. That's 25 hours 0 minutes and 8 seconds

Comment: How i can convert this  $starttime  =  "13:09"; in 12hour format for ex :01:09

Comment: Should be easy using `strtotime`. Or you can just explode and minus 12 from the hour part :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the time elapsed to process something, let's say to execute a function, you can easily do it with PHP [microtime](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Assume you want to find time elapsed to execute function test, here how you do this.

```
public function test()
{
$time_start = microtime(true);
/* 
  Your code 
    goes here
*/
$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = (($time_end - $time_start) / 60) * 60;

echo $execution_time; //This will show you the execution time in seconds.    

}
```

If you want, you can add this seconds to any previous time stamp you saved, in order to get the execution terminated time in hh:mm:ss format. Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I dont have endtime even i want to find endtime

Comment: To get the endtime, simply add the execution time to your previous time stamp. That will give you what you want. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand exactly what you are looking for

```
<?php
$hour = "24:60:08";        // 24 hour 60 min 8 min total hour 
$starttime  = "13:09";
$hourArray=explode(":", $hour);
$starttimeArray=explode(":", $starttime);
$endtimearray=array();
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    //Verifyng time is set else making it zero
    if (!isset($hourArray[$i]))
    $hourArray[$i]=0;
    if (!isset($starttimeArray[$i]))
    $starttimeArray[$i]=0;

    $endtimearray[$i]=$hourArray[$i]-$starttimeArray[$i];   
}
echo $endtimearray[0];
for ($i=1;$i<3;$i++)
echo ":$endtimearray[$i]";
```

Hopefully This is what you are looking for.